# Как реализовать совместное редактирование списка ToDol ist

Tags: php

Появилась идея создать небольшое приложение ToDo list. В качестве повышения сложности, решил реализовать редактирование списка несколькими пользователями. Какие способы реализации подобной функции существуют ?

Comment: Точно так же, как в блогах добавление постов, в постах добавление комментариев и т.п... Вы для начала реализуйте хотя бы просто листы чтоб кто угодно добавлять мог

Comment: Прошу прощение за неточность. Вопрос именно в одновременном использовании одно списка , нескольким пользователями . С помощью чего их привязать к одному и тому же списку ?

Comment: к примеру, так -> `users(id, name,...), lists (id, title,...), users_lists (id, user_id, lists_id)`